# Set LocalName property of an ATTRIBUTE-NODE in java DOM

Tags: java, dom, xml-namespaces

I have an XML of the form

`<root xmlns:ns2="prop" xmlns:ns3="prop2" .... etc
...
..
</root>`

I need to change the ns2, ns3 etc. to meaningful names.
However on org.w3c.dom.Node object though there is getLocalName method existing but no setLocalName available.

Please let me know if there is anyway I can do the required change?
Even the hacky ones are welcome though the ones with concrete implementation are preferred.

Comment: `localName` does not refer to the prefixes, it refers to the element names (e.g. the local name of `ns3:xyz` is `xyz`, not `ns3`).

Comment: I know that but I need to change local name itself .. if you look at the xml structure I am referring, In my case ns2 ns3 etc atre local names.

Answer (score 0):

changing those attributes is not going to help you.  those attributes are tied to prefixes used by nodes nested under this root node.  what you need to do is go through the document and change the prefixes of those nodes.

Comment: But I have to change those attributes for my purpose. Is there a way to clone the node and change its local name and replace it for the original node ?

Comment: Because they are supposed to be custom namespace prefixes for the xml I am generating.                                                             For instance :                                                           If I have an entry xmlns:ns3="Some namespace" in root element , I will have child elements like <ns3:abc>...</ns3:abc> etc,           I am able to give custom prefixes for child elements using setPrefix method. as for instance I have changed all occurences of ns3 to custom name. I need to reflect the same in root element listing too,

Comment: (cont..d)for which I am not having any DOM inbuilt method.                  Hope you got what I am trying to say.

Comment: yes, and my point is, if you change the prefix on all the child elements, the xmlns attributes will get updated automatically.  you don't generally _need_ to manually manipulate the xmlns attributes (they aren't really true attributes anyway).  you just define your elements with the namespace/prefix you desire and the DOM code will do the rest.